# HttpUtility.ParseQueryString value and Key

Tags: c#, uri, query-string

I'm trying to remove the key and value of a HttpUtility.ParseQueryString , but I am not able to get the key and value.
(ex: //somesite.com/someaction?article=1&lang=en )

I want something like :

```
           [
            {"article",1}, 
            {"lang","en"}
           ];
```

Any idea how to get there ?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this a little more? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I can get one specific Attribute from querystring (like `Request.QueryString["fullname"];`), but I want get all Attributes from querystring listed, if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all keys and values:

```
string[] allKeys = Request.QueryString.AllKeys
    .Select(k => "key: " + k + " value: " + Request.QueryString[k])
    .ToArray();
```

Modify the `Select` method to get the data structure you want (other than `string[]`), for example:

```
string[][] allKeys = Request.QueryString.AllKeys
    .Select(k => new string[] { k, Request.QueryString[k]})
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: And I can do the same if I have an `var uri =  new Uri("http://www.example.com?foo=1&bar=2");` ??

Comment: @MarcoPalma Your question is about `HttpUtility.ParseQueryString`, not `Uri`. If you want to parse uri's query string, then modify your question, please.

Comment: You're Rigth, tanks for anwser